# How to add an icon to VS project with relative path

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to add an icon to an executable file produced in Visual Studio 2010 from a relative path since the project is intended to be distributed and compiled on several machines but I can't get it working. These are the steps that I perform:

1. Right-click on Resources -> Add Resource -> Icon -> Import
2. Then I import my icon which is two directories upward from my project ../../images/icon.ico
3. Then I compile and I get the icon on the exe but if I open the auto generated .rc file with a text editor, the path to the icon is hard coded and if I move the project on another computer with a different file structure it doesn't compile.

Is there a way to set the icon with a relative path? Or to make the .rc file work with relative paths?

Comment: Surely you need to change the icon to a compiled resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the resource editor will only generate a relative path if the resource is located inside your project directory or a subdirectory of directory.  You could just edit the .rc file yourself.  Right-click the .rc file in the Solution Explorer window, Open With, select the Source Code Editor and edit the ICON statement.

Beware the future headache you'll induce by doing this.  This doesn't just go wrong on that other machine, sooner or later this will go wrong on your machine as well.  When you check-out the project in a different directory or that images folder has just disappeared.  The absolute path as generated by the resource editor solves that first mishap.  Not the second one of course.  Always favor copying a resource file to your project directory so you can easily check it in to source control and cannot lose the file.

Comment: I copied the icon in the project folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this problem, our projects share the same disk partition -- a dedicated disk partition -- then you can enter an absolute path, but without typing the drive letter, such as `\path\to\my\icon.ico`.

Besides working in `rc.exe`, this also works in the IDE.

These are the advantage of dedicated disk partition + absolute file notation:

- Create as many partition as needed to maintain trunk, stable and branches separately, without breaking resource compiler
- If you have lots of static libraries spread over your project partition and need to `#include` library relative **.rc** files to produce a statically linked **.exe** you can add `#include <\path\to\your\static\library\resource.rc>` in you **compile time directive** box. This will also work with the **rc.exe** tool.